# How do we do dynamic layout components ins Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I've tried a bunch of stuff from what I've seen, but I can't get dynamic layout components to work.

This is my code:

```
<script setup>
import DefaultLayout from "@/components/wrappers/SiteWrapper.vue";
import SimpleLayout from "@/layouts/Simple.vue"
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { computed } from 'vue';

const route = useRoute();
const layout = computed(() => {
  return route.meta.layout || DefaultLayout;
});
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>
```

Vue router looks like this:

```
{
  path: '/terms-and-conditions/:slug',
  name: 'TermsAndConditions',
  component: TermsAndConditions,
  props: true
  props: true,
  meta: { layout: 'SimpleLayout' }
},
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: You're passing 'SimpleLayout' as a string, which doesn't work. I'm not sure what's the right way to fix it though, which is why I only leave this comment. Probably you should import it in Vue router and pass it like you pass DefaultLayout in the other file. Maybe this helps too: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/composing-layouts-with-vue-router/

Answer (score 1):

To use component name strings with the `:is` property the component needs to be **locally registered** via Options API, not just imported.  You can add an additional Options API `<script>` tag to do this:

```js
<script>
import SimpleLayout from "@/layouts/Simple.vue"
export default {
  components: { SimpleLayout }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, with Composition API and `<script setup>` you can return the component itself instead of the string:

```js
const layout = computed(() => {
  return route.meta.layout === 'SimpleLayout' ? SimpleLayout : DefaultLayout;
});
```